# Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform JNI

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, 64-bit

I have a Problem :D im working on a self generated DLL with JNI. 
I have generated the DLL with Visual Studio 2013, for 64Bit machines. I have already checked with Dependency Walker if my DLL is really 64 Bit, and it is. Then i tried to use the DLL in my Java source (Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) Java Version 1.7.0_71-b14 64 Bit Version).

When i run my Java Programm i get the errormessage Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform in this line.

```
     static 
     {
         System.loadLibrary("iomemjava");
     }
```

I have already spend 2 days in this problems and searched stackoverflow and some other forums. I'm really out of Ideas what could possibly be wrong.

So far and in the hope you guys and girls can help
Martin

Comment: You say the DLL is 64-bit, but apparently your computer disagrees. Your computer is probably right. Are you sure it's picking up the right version of the DLL?

Comment: yes, the DLL should be 64 Bit, Dependency Walker and Visual Studio tell that to me, also everything in the DLL is 64 Bit (DW). And i have also generated a 32 Bit DLL for testing.
so everything loooks like the DLL is 64 bit. 

Maybe Dependency Walker or Visual studio are make mistakes. But they shouldn't i have checked everything twice

Comment: Apparently then Java is picking up your 32-bit test DLL instead of the 64-bit version. See my answer below on how you can tell Java where to look for DLLs.

Comment: Tip: Since you use Dependency Walker, you could also use its Profile feature. It would show the paths of the DLLs loaded at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java uses the system property `java.library.path` as the path to find native libraries. When you start your application, define this property on the command line with the `-D` option and make it point to the directory that contains the DLL. For example:

```
C:\MyProject> java -Djava.library.path=C:\MyProject\nativelib com.mypackage.MyProgram
```

where `C:\MyProject\nativelib` is the directory that contains the DLL you want to use.

Comment: Thanks :D i have changed it that way and now it compiles :D now i got a other error but that has nothing to do with the type of the DLL but with the coding and thats something i can do myself :D 

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

go to the link http://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/native/
find the latest one
[image]

download tomcat-native-XXX-win32-bin.zip
open the zip file. find the tcnative-1.dll under X64 folder
[image]

finally, replace the .dll in the tomcat bin with the .dll in the zip file